# Where is the setting for the suggestion to wrap incompatible argument for TextView's setText() method using the static method String.valueOf()?

Tags: android-studio, inspection

Recently I found out that my Android Studio no longer gives the suggestion to wrap an incompatible argument for the `TextView`'s `setText()` method using the `String.valueOf()` method.
I sometimes forget to convert the value/variable that I'm going to pass as argument to `String`, but Android Studio usually gives me a warning AND suggestions to wrap the value/variable, as long as it is possible. Now, for example, when I do this:

```
double x = 10.567;
textView.setText(double);
```

Android Studio will **still** give me a red error warning, but the only suggestion in there is "Cast parameter to 'int'".
[image]
[image]

It used to give me the option to automatically insert the `String.valueOf()` method call, which is very helpful.

Is it just me or this is how it is now? There was an update a few days ago.
Did I mess up some settings in my Android Studio? Can someone tell me how to fix it?
I've looked through the Inspections settings and I haven't found it, if there's even a setting for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the update changes the mechanism, or you can click on the "More actions" in the prompt to see if other options available.

`setText()` can accept `String` or `int`, if you pass in `int` value, compiler will expect it is `String` resource ("R.string.xxx"), which is `int` type. Just memorize this, you don't need to rely on the prompt any more.

Comment: The "More actions" only shows the same "Cast parameter to 'int'" option.  
It's not too big of a deal, but it's still a nice-to-have feature. Sometimes I even "exploit" it to write more efficiently, like in the example I'd intentionally put an incompatible type, the red error underwave would come out, and I'd just press Alt+Enter and pick the "Wrap with String.valueOf()" option.